# How to redirect URL with port to URL with context?

Tags: apache, apache2

I have a server with **apache(2.4.18)** installed

I have installed multiple applications on the server like Grafana, Sonarqube, and MySQL enterprise monitor(MEM)

Each application has URL like this

```
http://test.com:9000

http://test.com:3000
```

I am looking for a solution which allows me to redirect this URL with the port to URL with context, something like that

```
http://test.com:9000  --> http://test.com/sonar

http://test.com:3000 --> http://test.com/grafana
```

I have added some code in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** file

```
Redirect permanent /sonar http://test.com:9000

Redirect permanent /grafana http://test.com:3000
```

but when I enter `http://test.com/sonar` in the web browser it redirects to `http://test.com:9000` URL only

I want `http://test.com/sonar` this URL to persists on Web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Redirect permanent`, server will send `301` response back to client (along with new `Location`). That will result in browser issuing a new request, this time to new Location, and also new location will be shown in browser address bar.
What you need is Reverse Proxy. For this you need to make sure that mod_proxy is enabled in your apache configuration (usually it is enabled by default), and put something like this in your `.conf` file:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass        /sonar   http://127.0.0.1:9000
ProxyPassReverse /sonar   http://127.0.0.1:9000
ProxyPass        /grafana http://127.0.0.1:3000
ProxyPassReverse /grafana http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

You will probably also have to make your applications aware that they are running under non-root context (by making some configuration changes):

http://docs.grafana.org/installation/behind_proxy/

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/

Comment: Hi,

I tried this but getting a blank page on /sonar context

Answer (score 0):

You need to proxy requests and not redirect them.
Use a ProxyPass directive as mentioned in the [official apache proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

For example add this location block inside your configuration:

```
<Location "/sonar">
    ProxyPass "http://test.com:9000"
</Location>
```

Comment: Hi,

I tried this but getting a blank page on /sonar context

Comment: Check out if your sonar config is set up correctly to receive the proxied requests.